# Displaying Transition Elements

Tags: css, hover

I have titles for each of the divs (bg class) on my site, but they only appear when hovered, when really I want them to appear on the page and then transition on hover. Below is my code.

CSS:

```
.caption {
  color:white;
  z-index:100;
  position:relative;
  word-spacing: 100px;
  font-size:12pt;
  -webkit-transition: font-size .4s ease-out 1s, word-spacing .4s ease-out 1.5s;
  -moz-transition: font-size .4s ease-out 1s, word-spacing .4s ease-out 1.5s;
  -o-transition: font-size .4s ease-out 1s, word-spacing .4s ease-out 1.5s;
  -ms-transition: font-size .4s ease-out 1s, word-spacing .4s ease-out 1.5s,  
  transition: font-size .4s ease-out 1s, word-spacing .4s ease-out 1.5s;
}
.bg:hover .caption {
  font-size:72px;
  word-spacing: 17px;
}
```

HTML:

```
 <div id='ne' class='bg'>
      <div class='overlay'>
        <span class='caption'>News</span>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: @avrilalejandro, I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: white text color disappears

Comment: @avrilalejandro my background is dark so you can see the white text.

Comment: then I do not understand your question

Comment: looks OK for me, I have added a dark bg (which, btw, you could have added to help yourself get a solution), anyways, it looks fine, not sure what you mean: http://jsfiddle.net/vn2abgzc/

Comment: @Fabio this is what I'm getting : http://jsfiddle.net/759jyvft/

Comment: see? this is what happens when you post incomplete code, it is as simple as to change opacity:0; to opacity:1; in .overlay

Comment: @Fabio that did work but then it displays the overlay that fades in as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, change you CSS to this:

```
.caption {
    font-family:'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-weight:100;
}
body {
    background: url('http://www.bootply.com/assets/example/bg_blueplane.jpg');
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
div.bg {
    position:fixed;
    width:50%;
    height:50%
}
#nw {
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background-image: url('clevelandnight.jpg');
    background-size:cover;
}
#ne {
    top:0;
    left:50%;
    background-image: url('news1.jpg');
    background-size:cover;
}
#sw {
    top:50%;
    left:0;
    background-image: url('drinks1.jpg');
    background-size:cover;
}
#se {
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    background-image: url('clevelandday.jpg');
    background-size:cover;
}
.overlay {
    height:100%;
    -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all .4s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all .4s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all .4s ease-out;
    transition: all .4s ease-out;
}
.bg:hover .overlay {
    background:rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
    opacity: 1;
    height:100%;
}
.caption {
    color:white;
    z-index:100;
    position:relative;
    word-spacing: 100px;
    font-size:12pt;
    -webkit-transition: font-size .4s ease-out 1s, word-spacing .4s ease-out 1.5s;
    -moz-transition: font-size .4s ease-out 1s, word-spacing .4s ease-out 1.5s;
    -o-transition: font-size .4s ease-out 1s, word-spacing .4s ease-out 1.5s;
    -ms-transition: font-size .4s ease-out 1s, word-spacing .4s ease-out 1.5s, transition: font-size .4s ease-out 1s, word-spacing .4s ease-out 1.5s;
}
.bg:hover .caption {
    font-size:72px;
    word-spacing: 17px;
}
```

[See fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/759jyvft/)

The background image is so you could see the effect since I couldn't see anything (black on black!) but of course, change it as you need.

**Explanation:**

Since [**opacity**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity) affects the entire element and its children, instead of playing with the whole opacity of the element, I simply used the [alpha channel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value#rgba%28%29) of the background, this way opacity is always `1` and all elements inside `.overlay` are visible

Comment: awesome. thank you very much. can i ask exactly what you changed?

Answer (score 0):

From `.overlay` change `opacity: 0` to `opacity: 1`

http://jsfiddle.net/759jyvft/2/